# Is Hayek in pro or in con of Equilibrium?

Tags: general-equilibrium, history-economic-thought

I had read twice the paper Economics and Knowledge and it seems to me like he is arguing against equilibrium analysis, but I don't know if I'm misunderstanding his arguments.